# Are there useful uses of readyState different from "4" (complete) in a XHR.onreadystatechange callback?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, readystate, onreadystatechange

Have you ever used an XHR object to intercept `onreadystatechange` with a `readyState` different from "4" (complete) ?

I'm curious to know if you ever trigger a function with the possible different values.
I cannot imagine a real use of the others states. Are they somewhat useful to do something?

Can give some practical examples if any ?

[I'm talking about these](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp):

- 0: request not initialized
- 1: server connection established
- 2: request received
- 3: processing request
- 4: request finished and response is ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it on an intranet I have developed for notification purposes.
By intercepting the state 3 I can notify the user that the request started.

I also use it to time the requests transmission times. I display the time elapsed between states 3 and 4.

Since I use MooTools I extended the Request class to fire the onStateChange event:

```
var EarlyRequest = new Class({Extends: Request,
 onStateChange: function() {
  this.fireEvent("onStateChange", [this.xhr.readyState]);
  this.parent();
 }
});
```

On an additional note. The definitions of the states that you posted (from w3cschools) are misleading, these are clearer to me (from http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#states):

- **UNSENT (numeric value 0)**
  The object has been constructed.
- **OPENED (numeric value 1)**
  The open() method has been successfully invoked. During this state request headers can be set using setRequestHeader() and the request can be made using the send() method.
- **HEADERS_RECEIVED (numeric value 2)**
  All redirects (if any) have been followed and all HTTP headers of the final response have been received. Several response members of the object are now available.
- **LOADING (numeric value 3)**
  The response entity body is being received.
- **DONE (numeric value 4)**
  The data transfer has been completed or something went wrong during the transfer (e.g. infinite redirects).